# iPad 2 camera programming example

Tags: camera, ipad

Can anyone point me to an example of a program using camera on iPad 2? Preferentialy an example working in the XCode simulator.

Thanks a lot

Krzys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the UIImagePickerController, but the camera mode won't work in the Simulator. For the simulator you can use the Library Mode and then just swap to camera mode when your ready to test on the device.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = pickerDelegate
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

and then use the delegate method to access the image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, what should be the pickerdelegte class?

Comment: Most likely you should set it to self i.e. pointing to the view controller in which its being used.